# Use key / certificate on ukey to sign data

Tags: c++, cryptography, digital-signature, cryptoapi, ocx

I want to get certificate from ukey, and sign data. Now I can get it, and succeeded in a console application program. But when I make it as an OCX control for Internet Explorer then it doesn't work.

When I use the following function:

```
CryptAcquireContext(&hProvder, NULL, my_provder_name, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)
```

it fails, returning `nte_bad_keyset`.

When I use `CRYPT_NEWKEYSET` or `CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET` instead of `0`, signing the data fails.

How can I create a signature using ukey?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you link to the "ukey" you're talking about? Note that your question contains a very low amount of code, adding some more code to the bottom of the question may give a better indication of the issues you are facing. Please always use at least one tag for your platform (I guessed C++, please adjust if not correct) and use highly visible tags (such as [tag:cryptography] in addition to more specific ones such as [tag:digital-signature])\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CryptAcquireContext(&hProvder, NULL, my_provder_name, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);

You want to get the csp which could be helpful for signature your file.In a desktop application,you can use the function with those parameters like that case.But in browser,you can't.
we want to get the default key container associated with the current user. Howerver, when certificates are created, they may be placed in a key container other than the default, so the default container doesn't exist.
why?
The problem appears to stem from the second parameter.
So, we must specify the name of key container as the second parameter.
Like this:
CryptAcquireContext(&hProvder, container_name, my_provder_name, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);

Comment: you can refer to this article: http://www.drdobbs.com/security/digital-signatures-with-the-microsoft-cr/184410585